# Why does Blender "click through" my mesh?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, interface, camera

https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sT5.jpg

[image: Clicking through]

Blender seems to be getting the ray trace completely wrong here and ignoring/"clipping through" the mesh. I'm pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> to create a new vertex but I've noticed this problem occurs with other operations too; the 3D cursor works fine however.

I only installed Blender the other day - don't think I've fiddled with any relevant settings.

I have an AMD CPU.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you have X-ray mode on.  To turn it on/off, you click on the icon in the top right corner that looks like 2 squares on top of each other

Comment: @ETHANDAY Nah, X-ray mode didn't change anything. I turned it on to see if it would fix it.

Comment: hm, then I don't know what is causing this

Comment: Blender's extrude new vertex with Ctrl+click tool never really worked that way by default. Enable snapping to face, create a different object and in Edit mode for *that* object Ctrl+click, then it will - that is essentially what manual retopology is. And what other operations were which suffer from that behaviour?

Comment: @MrZak Snapping to edge made it work for one side of the mesh... if I pan over to the opposite side, the same problem occurs!

Comment: Just decided to snap to vertex and snapped the weirdly positioned ones to nearby correct ones, so we're good.